# Decoding speech-to-text string to date and time

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

In my Android app I ask the user to say "when" a certain action should be triggered. I get a string with his words, i.e.:

- Tomorrow eleven o'clock
- August the first quarter past seven

I wonder if there is an API that can decode those strings to something like:

- DateTime("2019-07-17T11:00:00Z");
- DateTime("2019-08-01T07:15:00Z");

The only approach I can imagine is to ask the user to say one value at time. "Say year" -> decode, "Say month" -> decode, etc... but it would be a terrible user-experience.

Because date and time are common information, I guess there is an API available. 
I did a Google search but I found nothing - perhaps I used wrong keywords.

Answer (score 4):

When a speech recognition system is trained, its input, among others, is a text where all numbers, dates, acronyms, etc. are coerced to textual representation. For example,

> "at 6:00pm at Ocean Dr"

would become

> "at six p. m. at ocean drive"

This process is called *text normalization*. Some sophisticated ASR systems, like Google Cloud Speech-to-Text, do the inverse as the last step of recognition and provide the functionally that you requested, but the result is often not stable and is highly context-dependent (which is good and bad at the same time). Personally I have not heard about a standalone *de-normalization* API or cloud service.

What I recommend instead is to take a look at *entity recognition* services like [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) and [Wit.ai](https://wit.ai/). Those are capable to convert speech or text to a structured form where date, time, currencies, and many more are recognized and returned to the user in a machine-readable form.